# Uniformly bounded solution to a dynamical system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that all the solution of the problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \dot{x}=15x+x^2+y-3x^3\\
      \dot{y}=4y^2-x-5y^3, \\
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
are uniformly bounded for $t\geq 0$.

I don't even know where to start: I tried bounding $\|(x,y)\|_2^2$ or its derivative with respect to $t$, but my attempts were unsuccessfull.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I proved, but i wasn't able at solving it.

Comment: You wasn't able to solve what?

Comment: To solve the exercise.

Comment: I have no idea, ok?

Comment: You make me always the same question!

Comment: You wrote that you proved something. What have you proved?

Comment: I am trying to help you. If the question stand as it is, it will probably be closed. If you have tried something, you must include it in the question, If you don't even know where to startm you also must include it in the question.

Comment: I'm stupid and I can't solve the exercise. I'proved a stupid thing. I proved to derive the function $\rho(x,y)=x(t)^2+y(t)^2$ trying to see if this derivative was 0. It is a stupid thing, but it is the only thing that came to my mind. You are surely smarter than me, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: ok i'll write right now that I don't know where to start

Comment: There is no need to call you stupid, I also don't know to answer plenty of questions. Just take a look in my questions tab and you will see it.

Answer (score 3):

Since:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2)=y\dot{y}+x\dot{x} = 15x^2+x^3-3x^4+4y^3-5y^4$$
we know that $$\frac{(x^2+y^2)'}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ is negative and bounded for any $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2$ is big enough - many thanks to [Ivan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/36248/ivan).

But any function that satisfies:
$$ -J\cdot f^2(t)\leq f'(t) \leq -K\cdot f^2(t),\quad J,K>0 \tag{2}$$
is bounded for $t\to +\infty$, since the solution of $(2)$ with an equality sign is a function that decays like $\frac{1}{t}$ for $t>0$.